# Recover corrupt neo4j Database after server crash graphdb.NotFoundException

Tags: java, neo4j, corruption

I have a neo4j database with several million nodes and about as many relationships. While running a program that was adding data to it, the JVM seems to have crashed. When I later tried to query the database using an index, it opened normally and retrieved some of the nodes, but at some point returned the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException:
>   Node[20924] not found. This can be because someone else deleted this
>   entity while we were trying to read properties from it, or because of
>   concurrent modification of other properties on this entity. The
>   problem should be temporary.  at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.ensureFullProperties(Primitive.java:601)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.ensureFullProperties(Primitive.java:579)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.hasProperty(Primitive.java:309)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.hasProperty(NodeImpl.java:53)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasProperty(NodeProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.hasProperty(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:66)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.hasProperty(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.Has.isMatch(Predicate.scala:203)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:30)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:30)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:390)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1156)    at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe.internalCreateResults(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:76)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:69)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$ExecutionPlanImpl$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:164)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$getLazyReadonlyQuery$1.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:139)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$getLazyReadonlyQuery$1.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:138)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.execute(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:38)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:72)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:66)
>     at querygraph.BasicStatsQueries.main(BasicStatsQueries.java:54)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException:
>   PropertyRecord[11853043] not in use   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PropertyStore.getRecord(PropertyStore.java:453)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PropertyStore.getLightRecord(PropertyStore.java:306)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.getPropertyRecordChain(ReadTransaction.java:185)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.loadProperties(ReadTransaction.java:215)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.nodeLoadProperties(ReadTransaction.java:239)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.loadNodeProperties(PersistenceManager.java:111)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.loadProperties(NodeManager.java:833)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.loadProperties(NodeImpl.java:143)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.ensureFullProperties(Primitive.java:596)
>     ... 23 more

There was only one thread (at least, that I started) running the query, and it was all reading, not writing. And though the exception claims that it's temporary, this happens every time I try to query this index. I therefore assume it has to do with the bad shutdown. I have had database corruptions before from forced shutdowns before I implemented code to prevent that, but neo4j was always able to recover the database, though it took a while. It seems that this is much worse.

When I looped through the index manually and added a try-catch, it began returning the error for every node in the index after the one listed above. Does that mean that all these nodes are non-existent, or corrupted? That would mean a significant (huge) loss of data, since there should be about a million nodes in the index. What can I do to recover the database?

I am using 1.9.2 and would love to upgrade to use labels and etc., but I need this database right now for some time-critical work and don't have time to change anything major right now.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

sorry that that happened to you. :( What kind of crash was that?

I would recommend making a backup of the database and then deleting and recreating the index.

When you cannot delete the index programmatically you can also delete the directory under
`/data/graph.db/index/lucene/node/<indexname>` when the database is shut down.

Then afterwards you can programmatically re-index your nodes using

for (Node n : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes()) {
   if (node.hasProperty("key"))
     db.index().forNodes("index").add(node,"key",node.getProperty("key"));
}

It would be great if you could get us the database for analytics.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this and mark this as the answer if it works. The JVM crash was probably caused by something in the program that was using neo4j - don't know if it was neo4j itself or one of the other components.  I'll find out if I can let you have the database, and if so, I'll send the server logs along.

Comment: I've seen you ask to see databases a few times in similar situations and it's great to know that neo is really on top of any issues - thanks!

Comment: Can I assume that you meant 'for (Node n : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes()) ?

Comment: I tried it, and unfortunately, it crashed again with the same error, on a node with a slightly smaller id. How can it think that these nodes exist if it can't find them in the graph, and there's no index? And what do I do now?

Comment: What exactly did you do for the fix?

Comment: Ran a program that opened the database and deleted the index. Then I checked to make sure that the index had been deleted and ran your code on the database. It ran until it hit a node with a similar id to the one it crashed on originally, and then crashed with the same error.